# Has the civil service law ever been challenged in court by a president?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, separation-of-powers

[The Pendleton Civil Service Reform Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendleton_Civil_Service_Reform_Act) is one of the main reason why Federal employees often considered themselves as having a lifetime tenure, [unable to be fired](http://www.thefiscaltimes.com/2015/07/17/Federal-Employees-Can-t-Hire-Best-Can-t-Fire-Worst). Although the act certainly had a valid motive, nevertheless, it would seem to be an unconstitutional violation of the separation of powers, Congress infringing on the ability of the President to run the executive branch the way he wants.

Is there any caselaw on the constitutionality of this law? Have there been any challenges to it on constitutional grounds, and if so were they upheld or denied? Are there any decisions or related laws that would tend to show that this is (or isn't) within the valid powers of Congress?

Comment: This is a history question, or possibly a political one, but I don't see how this has any bearing to law.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about political history, not the law or legal process.

Comment: @Nij how is asking whether a law has ever been challenged not a legal question?

Comment: Because it's not about the law itself, it's about what someone may have done or why they might have done it. Asking whether the law would bar the president from doing so, and on what basis it would or would not, would be a legal question.

Comment: @Nij I disagree that that isn't a legal question, the US legal system is partially based on precedent, and constitutional challenges are a part of the Judiciary's responsibility and oversight.  However, I might adjust the question to be more general, as in "Has this act ever been challenged and found to be constitutional, or does existing precedent for similar congressional restraints on the Executive's personnel management show that Congress is within their constitutional authority to pass this law?"

Comment: I don't see why this question should be closed when a simple edit would make it proper.

Comment: I think that this is on topic and the short answer is yes, but I haven't had the time to find the relevant precedent.

Comment: The President's powers as stated in the Constitution are actually pretty scanty.  His Constitutional authority over executive departments is to be able to require written advice from their heads.